# How to access custom options of a product in magento from observer event

Tags: php, magento

I have 2 custom option text fields associated with a product called Location To and Location From,

I have set up a Module that has an Observer for `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` with a method called getLocationCoords, how would I get access to these two fields from the event object that passed to my method.

I need these 2 fields so I can reverse geocode them which I think I will be able to do myself.

Once I get the 2 sets of coordinates how would I go about storing them with the product so I would be able to see them associated with the product when an order is paced?

=======================
edit addded ============================

What i have tried so far

```
 public function getLocationCoords(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // Retrieve the product being updated from the event observer
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    // Write a new line to var/log/product-updates.log
    $name = $product->getName();
    $sku = $product->getSku();
    Mage::log(
        "{$name} ({$sku}) updated",
        null, 
        'product-updates.log'
    );
    foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
        $type = "Custom Option TYPE: " . $o->getType();
        $title = "Custom Option TITLE: " . $o->getTitle();
         Mage::log(
            "{$type} ({$title}) custom option {$o}",
            null, 
            'product-updates.log'
        );
    }
}
```

It all works except getting the values of the custom options,  i will try the answer below and see where i get

when i print out the var dump of the option object this is what i get

```
2012-12-11T15:19:45+00:00 DEBUG (7): array (
  'option_id' => '1',
  'product_id' => '1',
  'type' => 'field',
  'is_require' => '1',
  'max_characters' => '0',
  'sort_order' => '0',
  'default_title' => 'Location To',
  'title' => 'Location To',
  'default_price' => '0.0000',
  'default_price_type' => 'fixed',
  'price' => '0.0000',
  'price_type' => 'fixed',
)
```

there is no value to the object

Answer (score 3):

There is also this event

```
 $eventName = sprintf('catalog_product_type_prepare_%s_options', $processMode);
    Mage::dispatchEvent($eventName, array(
        'transport'   => $transport,
        'buy_request' => $buyRequest,
        'product' => $product
    ));
```

With processMode either full or lite. The buy_request should have your details and you can then add a new option on the product

```
$product->addCustomOption('my_option','my_value');
```

Not tested but do let us know how you are getting on.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that by the time that event is dispatched you will need to access the sales quote object from the cart session, which smells bad to me. Try the [`checkout_cart_product_add_after` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php#L296) event and get access to the quote item as follows:

```
public function geoConversion ($obs)
{
    $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
    /* @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item */

    //I believe the custom options will be in here, not sure
    $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();

    // your logic 
}
```

I haven't checked this, but it's a bit better an event to use. However, there are lots of considerations when customizing the add to cart process (admin-created orders and updates of existing cart items for example), so test, test, test. Also, there is another event which may be useful/more appropriate: [`sales_quote_product_add_after` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php#L957).

Further, this behavior could also be achieved by giving these products a custom type model based on - or by observing events dispatched in - `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract`.

It's dizzying.

Comment: you put me in the right direction , but i found my options a different way, i have answered below

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get to get access to quote item and from that i was able to access the values of the custom attributes. I had two options and after some debugging i realised my options were being called option_1 and option_2 , from that i was able to get the value and set them to my variables.

```
public function getLocationCoords(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

    $locationFrom = '';
    $locationTo = '';

    foreach ($item->getOptions() as $o) {   
        if($o['code'] == 'option_2'){
            $locationFrom = $o['value'];
        }
        if($o['code'] == 'option_1'){
            $locationTo = $o['value'];
        }

    }
     Mage::log("the location from = ".$locationFrom);
     Mage::log("the location to = ".$locationTo);

 }
```